# Joi custom validation extension not being applied

Tags: validation, joi

I've been paring down my already simple custom validation function trying to get it to work but I have been unsuccessful. Here's what i'm down to in my custom `joi.ts`:

```
const Joi = require('joi')

const joiExtended = Joi.extend({
  type: 'address',
  base: Joi.string(),
  messages: {
    'address.invalid': 'invalid',
  },
  rules: {
    address: {
      validate: (value, helpers) => {
        console.log('Validating address', value)
        // Fail for all inputs as a test
        return { value, errors: helpers.error('address.invalid') }
      },
    },
  },
  // Add further extensions here
})

console.log(joiExtended.attempt('x', joiExtended.address()))
console.log(joiExtended.attempt('foo', joiExtended.number()))
```

When I run this from the command line w/ `node joi.ts` I see that:

1. `Validating address` is never printed to the console
2. `x` **is** printed to the console
3. Sanity check on `foo` being a number throws with `Error [ValidationError]: "value" must be a number`

I'm running Joi 17.6.0 on MacOS Monterey. I've read through [the docs](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#extensions) (as well as digging through source code) extensively. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample in the documentations, you should move `validate` out of `rules` and place it in the root :

```
const joiExtended = Joi.extend({
   type: "address",
   base: Joi.string(),
   messages: {
       "address.invalid": "invalid",
   },
   validate: (value, helpers) => {
       console.log("Validating address", value);
       // Fail for all inputs as a test
       return { value, errors: helpers.error("address.invalid") };
   },
   // Add further extensions here
 });
```

And you wouldn't need `rules` for your current implementation.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, cheers sir